# Is jam a davar charif?

Tags: halacha, kashrut-kosher, food

I learned that juicy fruit are considered a davar charif.  Is jam or preserves made from such types of fruit also a davar charif?  Why or why not?

Comment: Where did you learn that juicy fruit are considered a davar charif?

Comment: @IsaacMoses I got mixed up.  I meant to ask about the halacha of duchka d'sakina (another knife halacha) - Chochmas Adom 49:9. But I don't know if I'm allowed to edit my question with the upvoted answer.

Comment: @YEZ Is this question/answer still useful to the world at large? If so, then why not leave it?

Answer (score 2):

The only juicy fruit that is charif is a lemon, see Shulchan Aruch Yoreh Deah siman 96 siff 4 & Shach about lemonade from nonjews.

There is also in the same siman siff 2 Peiros Chamutzim, fruits preserved in vinegar, like borscht. Perhaps that is what you are reffering to?

In general a davar charif loses that status when mixed with other ingredients, such as the sugar for making a jam.

Comment: This is not the only opinion out there. Some say pineapple, for instance, is Charif.

Comment: @Double AA interesting. Can you source that?

Comment: See the list [here](http://www.practicalhalacha.com/c/6005/kosher_kashrut?view=halachot) for example. I'm not claiming this is universally held, but neither is the claim in your answer.

Comment: @Double AA there is no real seffer that says pineapple is charif. In fact saying lemon is charif was a chidush. The kaf hachaim even mentions that pomegranate is not charif. Even in the article you mention the author explains pineapple as sour. Sour is not what quaifies as charif. Anyone who is machmir on pineapple is mistaken.

Comment: & even olives are not charif unless they were pickled see Shach in siman 114 s.k. 12

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/No_true_Scotsman Even onions aren't Charif if they aren't sharp. Should we not list them then? Are you really calling [R Heineman](http://www.practicalhalacha.com/about/loa.php) mistaken?